# Is insert empty row and get last id save in php mysql?

Tags: php

I have a registration form. If a user starts the form I insert a empty row in my mysql-table and get the last id like that:

```
$db=startConnection();
$query=" INSERT INTO form  VALUES ()";
$result=$db->query($query)
    or die($db->error);
$id=$db->insert_id;
```

But now I worry - isn't it possible that two users register at the same time and both get the same $id from the code above? For example, if two people hit the registration form at the same time and both "insert" queries are executed, and afterwards both people will get the same last insert_id?

Comment: Why creating an empty row? Isn't it possible to create the row not until the user actually submitted the form and you have data to put in the row?

Comment: @Flixer in my registration form the user is able to upload data. I want to upload the data in a folder which is named by his id. Thats why  I need the id in first place.

Comment: Then wait for the user to upload the data and create the id and folder when he does so and then save the data.

Comment: What if the user reloads the form? It will create a new empty row? You'll end up having a ton of empty rows slowing your queries and stuff.

Comment: @Adam: If the has the possibility to upload data, why not sending it with the form itself (so that you can create the db entry and the folder in the same request)? Or put the uploaded files into a temporary folder as long as the user has not yet an id.

Comment: @Flixer If two users use the form at the same time how can I distinguish which file belongs to which user in my temporary folder? I want the user to upload the files first and after that he should provide his name etc.

Comment: @lascort my form table consists only of one column. I store in a session if a folder has been created for a user. I add the user to my members table when registration process has been completed. I dont add empty rows in my members table

Comment: @Adam You can save it in the session informations or pass it as parameter through the forms for your registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP runs on the server and not on the clients side.
Therefor once the first user submits the second submit will be executed after the first one has finise

Comment: Does it mean that two php pages cant be executed at the same time? For example when 10000 people are loading my page than there is one person that has to wait until all other 9999 other pages have been finished loading?

Comment: @Adam - No the webserver that handles your requests is multi-threaded and can handle multiple requests in parallel... there is a limit to the number of parallel requests that it will handle, and subsequent requests will be queued on a first-come-first-served basis as each thread becomes available again